# Is there any 'group async wait' for sidekiq's tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Like javascript's Promise.all can wait all requests finished and then do the following job.

For example, I have A, B, C tasks:

C needs A and B both finished to run and use the results calculated by A and B.

(Because 3 processes are all very expensive computation so they're put in sidekiq queue to run)

Comment: Your question appears to be "Can I run A and B and when they are complete get their output and use them to run C?" and the answer is yes. If you want a more useful answer then I recommend [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with a [mre] and a lot more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Sidekiq [`Batches`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) which is available with Sidekiq Pro.

Batches will let you orchestrate your jobs in this manner and let `A` and `B` run in parallel. After completion of batch, you can allocate a callback and trigger `C`. Read more about [callbacks here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches#callbacks).

```
class MyCallback
  def on_success(status, options)
    # Initiate call for C
  end
end

batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
batch.on(:success, MyCallback)
batch.jobs do
  [a, b].each { |job| GenericJobWorker.perform_async(job) }
end
puts "Just started Batch #{batch.bid}"
```